# load repository with constructor parameters in Web API (1)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm trying to get the following scenario using autofac but I'm not sure how my code will be built to get this up & running.

I have a repository class, this repository class needs to get a project key (string) on initialization (constructor). I want to instantiate this repository in initialization of my "Initialize" method provided to my by Web Api, because the project key will be available in my route.

so instead of calling "new ProductRepository(projectKey)", I want to use Autofac. Can someone point me in the right direction? I didn't find any way to send in specific data to the container in web api, since the container/builder is only available in the appStart.
Should I make the container available as a singleton so that I can approach it, or is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in  your initialization code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var container = builder.Build();
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

in your controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyController(IComponentContext container)
    { 
        var key = new NamedParameter("projectKey", "keyFromRoute");
        var repository = container.Resolve<ProductRepository>(key);
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: I disagree with giving service classes direct access to `IComponentContext`. It's better to take advantage of https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Delegate-Factories

Comment: @Jim Bolla thanks for the info, it gave me (finally) more insight into the delegate factories. It is indeed a cleaner method

Comment: Good comment, I can imagine to restrict access to the component context, however, we are developers and should know what we are doing when we use it, so I could imagine that this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi/) that provides a `DependencyResolver` for WebApi that integrates with AutoFac.  Create the DependencyResolver, assign it to the config, register your controllers in the autofac container.

Comment: Hey Darrel, I have that one. I have set the dependencyresolver to the autofac web api dependency resolver, only I cannot use this dependencyresolver to send in parameters, or can I? When I use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver, I can only send in a type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions because you didn't provide your code, but I think you have something like this:

```cs
public class ProductRepository
{
    public ProductRepository(DbContext dbContext, int projectKey)
    {
    }
}

public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly Func<int, ProductRepository> _repoFactory;

    public SomeController(Func<int, ProductRepository> repoFactory)
    {
        _repoFactory = repoFactory;
    }

    public void DoStuff(int projectKey)
    {
        var repo = _repoFactory(projectKey);
        repo.DoStuff();
    }
}


public class RepositoryModule : Module
{
    public override Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>();
    }
}
```